# UIWebview editable content Scrolling and scroll indicator issue?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm using for uiwebview loaded html file paginated based on the device size. So that I's using following script in the didfinish of the webview. It paginated based on the device size.

```
NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
"if (mySheet.addRule) {"
"mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
"} else {"
"ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
"mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
"}"
"}";

NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.bounds.size.height, webView.bounds.size.width];
NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: left;')"];
NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];

[webviewone stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

[webviewone stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

[webviewone stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

[webviewone stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];
```

The above script paginated html file 'n' no.of pages.

It shown the first page out of 'n' numbers.

Loaded html file added editable as true.

```
<body contenteditable='true'>
```

My problem are:

1. When am going to select text in the webview it will jump to some other page.
2. In webview scroll indicator does not show the full webview frame.